# PHP : override_function doesn't override even if bool true is returned

Tags: php, function, require

I'm using the ovverride_function installed from apd.so library via pecl

It doesn't seem to work as expected

This is my script

```
function my_require($path) {
    echo "HELLO\n";
    echo $path;
}


$b = override_function('require', '$path', 'return my_require($path);');
var_dump($b);
require './index.php';
```

What I expected was to see as output

```
bool(true)
HELLO
./index.php
```

Instead I got

```
bool(true)

Warning: require(./index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test/script/test.php on line 14
```

So even if the function seemed to work (bool true) the require function still acts as the old one.

Any idea?

Comment: IIRC `require` is not a function, it's a language construct like `function` or `echo`. Try calling `require index.php` (without the `()`), it will still work while calling a normal function without the `()` wont. The documentation does not explicitly says it is, but it is listed under "Control Structures", so that is why `override_function` might not work for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is not a function, it's a language construct like `function` or `echo`. Try calling `require index.php` (without the `()`), it will still work while calling a normal function without the `()` wont. The documentation does not explicitly says it is, but it is listed under "Control Structures", so that is why `override_function` does not work for this `require` (or any other language constructs).